# Puppet manifest example

Tags: configuration, puppet

Can anyone point me to a full example (tar/zip) directory of a Puppet manifest?  I get the guides but it would be way easier just to look at a working directory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's right there in the [Puppet wiki](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Complete_Configuration)

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I lay out my puppet installed on the puppetmaster

```
/etc/
  |
  `- puppet/
        |
        +-- manifests/
        |        |
        |        +---- site.pp
        |        |
        |        +---- nodes.pp
        |        |
        |        +---- os/
        |        |      |
        |        |      +- base.pp
        |        |      |
        |        |      `- redhat.pp
        |        |
        |        `---- classes/
        |                  |
        |                  `-- aliases.pp
        |
        +-- modules/
               |
               +-- sshd/
               |     |
               |     +-- files/
               |     |
               |     +-- mainfests/ 
               |     |       |
               |     |       `--- init.pp
               |     |
               |     `-- templates/
```

My recommendation is to keep as much as possible in modules.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a tarball, but I have written a Puppet tutorial which takes you step by step through creating the required directories and files, and gives you a working template configuration to get started:

http://bitfieldconsulting.com/puppet-tutorial

So far it covers installing Puppet, setting up the starting manifests, how Puppet resources work, authorising your first client, and controlling a simple service.

Answer (score 3):

I'm personally a huge fan of [Wikipedia's](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/gitweb?p=operations/puppet.git) online repository of Puppet configs. You can read details and find the git clone url from their [blog entry](http://blog.wikimedia.org/2011/09/19/ever-wondered-how-the-wikimedia-servers-are-configured/).